# Trouble visualizing a second-order cone constraint

Tags: convex-optimization, convex-geometry, second-order-cone-programming

I have this problem from Boyd's optimization textbook:

> A standard form for the SOCP model is  $$\text{minimize } f^Tx
> \\\text{subject to: }‖A_ix+b_i‖_2 ≤ c_i^Tx + d_i, i= 1,\dots,m$$ where we see that the variables $(A_ix+b_i,c^T_ix+d_i)$ should belong to a second-order cone of appropriate size.

---

I don't see why the variables are in a second-order cone. According to the text, a second-order cone is the set

$$C = \left\{ (x, t) \in \Bbb R^{n+1} : \| x \|_2 \leq t \right\}$$

is $t$ the same as $c_i^Tx + d_i$? Can someone tip me off to how this is a cone? It seems like a set of all hyperplanes less than or equal to a line for each i ?

Comment: Which book? Boyd & Vandenberghe's *Convex Optimization*?

Comment: Just use different dummy variables in the description of $C$ and it will become clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cone $C$ can be visualized as in https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/cqo.html#quadratic-cones. In 3 dimensions it really is like an ice-cream cone.

And then instead of the pair $(t,x)$ you have the pair $(c^Tx+d,Ax+b)$, and the inequality they satisfy remains the same, so it is just some affine transformation of the cone $C$ (squeezing, stretching, shifting, rotating). See also https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/cqo.html#second-order-cones

Comment: Thanks for your answer; I read the link. How can I get the intuition to what is going on in the transformation?

Comment: @Frank Well it's just arbitrary linear transformations. The important thing is that SOCP is a certain way of writing certain quadratic constraints and being able to recognize when to use it. Try not to overthink the general form but look at some concrete examples.

Comment: Thanks. Things like this drive me crazy, if you happen to run across a good chapter of a text that is specifically about cones, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to code it:
[Code](https://github.com/aruntakhur/ConvexOptimization/blob/main/SOCP_Constraints.m)
and record it:
[VideoLink](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BhdNFFyta4c&ab_channel=ArunChauhan)

Hope this may helpful to you.